# Add a column and populate it in a single transaction with Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, transactions

I'm making an update script for a given data base. The script must

- *Update various things*
- Add a column to a table
- *Update various things*
- Populate this column with specific values
  (based on various calculations done in C#)
- *Update various things*

The script must either succeed or fail AND leave the database unchanged.

My idea was to do it in a single transaction, but I get an error when populating the column:

```
This operation conflicts with another pending operation on this transaction.
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, no way. Sorry, You requirements are not cmopatible with the way SQL Server requires DML statements to be isolated.